# R - Creating a subset by removing data that are factors

Tags: r

I have a dataset with missing values that contains both numeric and categorical variables. I plan on imputing the missing values by creating a subset for the numeric variables, creating a subset for the categorical variables and then applying the relevant `mice` methods on each.

I am currently trying to create the subset for the numeric variables but I am having trouble doing this. I am trying to create this subset by removing columns that are factors (i.e. categorical).

```r
dataCont <- subset(data, select = -c(data %>% Filter(f = is.factor) %>% names))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in -c(data %>% Filter(f = is.factor) %>% names) : 
  invalid argument to unary operator
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  display list redraw incomplete
2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  invalid graphics state
3: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  invalid graphics state
```

Would appreciate any guidance if possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a `-` in your code that should not be there in `select=-c(d....`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `Filter` as

```
library(dplyr)
Filter(is.factor, data) %>%
   names
```

---

In `tidyverse`, we can also do

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   select_if(is.factor) %>%
   select(contVar)
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response! for anyone else who runs into a similar problem, I was able to resolve my issue with the feedback above as follows:

```contVar <- Filter(is.numeric, data) %>% names
dataCont <- subset(data,select= c(contVar))
```